# FFT in LabView using DAQ

Tags: fft, labview

Familiar with the FFT and LabView. Can I use LabView to compute and display the FFT of an analog signal in real-time rather than computing it from a data array?

Comment: FFT requires a batch of samples to work on, where do you store those samples?

Comment: Yea, I understand that. I was reading online that I needed some plug-in to be able to do real-time analysis, is that true or can I accomplish it with the blocks that are included

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pure programming question

Answer (score 1):

LabVIEW includes a point-by-point FFT function that outputs an array representing the FFT result with each input sample. As I recall, you input the array size of the result that you need. The function takes some time to settle, meaning that you will need to input some number of samples before the results are meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You can use the "Spectral Measurements" assistant to perform the FFT of analog waveforms. If you don't use very high sample rates and the number of samples is limited, you can calculate the FFT in the same data acquisition cycle. In my experience you have no problem with 10kHz sampling and 10k samples per loop cycle.

[image: FFT in labview with DAQmx]